# How to customize a list in Flex mobile application

Tags: apache-flex, list, view, mobile-application

the thing I mean cannot be probably done with the  component, but I don't know how is the component I want called. I would like to achieve a list but with sort of "icon look". You could say some sort of springboard navigation. It would really help me if someone new what I mean.

Here is just a quick sketch in Photoshop how it should look like:
http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/849/hown.png/

The item is the one actual item in the list or something.

I will appreciate every answer and possible solution, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any reason you cannot use a [DataGroup](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/DataGroup.html) wrapper around a [Scroller](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/Scroller.html) with a [TileLayout](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/layouts/TileLayout.html) and use the [IconItemRenderer](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/components/IconItemRenderer.html)?

Comment: If it would get me to the point where I want to be it wouldn't probably be a problem. I want to fill the list or in this case data group with information gathered from an XML file or later from a database, so if it will work with this I wouldn't mind to make the change in my code

Comment: Actually, you might be able to use a list and change the layout to a TileLayout.  Either way, you'll need the icon renderer to show the images or use your own custom renderer.

Comment: So I put the TileLayout into the List and it works really great, well almost exactly as I wanted to, so great thanks to you! Right now I just have to figure out the right measures so it looks neat and nice. But thanks, because I wouldn't probably figure that out, since I started using Flash Builder about a week ago and that was my first experience with ActionScript :D...

Answer (score 0):

I'm not that familiar with the mobile version of Flex, but in ordinary Flex this is just a matter of defining a renderrer class for your List control and use a clickable image (or some Image Button class) as the renderrer.